# How to update the value of one column dF after matching the rows of from another column from different dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to replace the values in the column(charge) of Data 'B' into the column(charge) of Data 'A' by comparing the two dataFrames.

Example:

```
data A:                          data B:

Codes  | charge                Codes  | charge
-----------------            ---------------------
Abc123    100                  Abc123    50
Abc345    75                   Abc345    75
Abc645    0                    Abc645    0
Abc456    200                  Abc456    200
Abc789    123
::  ::    ::
::  ::    ::
```

So on and so forth

Data 'B' has predetermined values for those codes. Please, can someone help me do this in python.

Comment: Could you rephrase and reformat your question? It's unclear what you want. Edit: nevermind, you reposted this question after it was already marked as duplicate.

Comment: Mike, it was not resolved actually

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: I have 2 dataFrames, Df1 and Df2. Df1 has a fields 'codes' and 'Charges'. These charges values are random. For that reason, i have created Df2 with pre-determined values for those codes. So match the codes from df1 and df2, i would replace the charges in df1 by df2.

Comment: Take a look at the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

You could to something like this:

```
for (df1_index, df1_row), (df2_index, df2_row) in zip(df1.iterrows(), df2.iterrows()):
    df1.at[df1_index, 'codes'] = df2_row['whatever']
    df1.at[df1_index, 'Charges'] = df2_row['whatever']
```

You can add if-statements as well inside the loop depending on how and when you like to join the DataFrames. But this is essentially how to loop through two DataFrames at a time.

Comment: Hey Tinu, I tried this logic but the values are not populating in the df from df2 after matching rows.

Comment: Updated my answer